# OpenCV is not installing

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, compiling

I have recently installing OpenCV 3.0.0 with the help of script "install-opencv.sh"
I have used command $ sudo bash install-opencv.sh

error are below 
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
unzip:  cannot find or open 3.1.0.zip, 3.1.0.zip.zip or 3.1.0.zip.ZIP.
rm: cannot remove ‘3.1.0.zip’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘opencv-3.1.0’: No such file or directory
install-opencv.sh: line 43: cd: OpenCV1: No such file or directory
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/neo" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
**strong text**

Script are below:-

```
 # KEEP UBUNTU OR DEBIAN UP TO DATE

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove


# INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

# Build tools:
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

# GUI:
sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libvtk6-dev

# Media I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev

# Video I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev

# Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev

# Python:
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

# Java:
sudo apt-get install -y ant default-jdk

# Documentation:
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen


# INSTALL THE LIBRARY (YOU CAN CHANGE '3.0.0' FOR THE LAST STABLE VERSION)

sudo apt-get install -y unzip wget
wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip
unzip 3.1.0.zip
rm 3.1.0.zip
mv opencv-3.1.0 OpenCV1
cd OpenCV1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig


# EXECUTE SOME OPENCV EXAMPLES AND COMPILE A DEMONSTRATION

# To complete this step, please visit 'http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian'.
```

Comment: Could you please check if _wget_ and _zip_ packages installed on your system ?

Comment: See here _sudo apt-get install -y unzip "wget wget" https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip_

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not ubuntu based, but is network issue. If you closely see it says : `error are below wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’` which means that your DNS server cannot find github.com . Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` and try to ping or `dig github.com` after you fix your dns server issue.

Comment: Hello guys !! This OPENCV script works well for ubuntu 15.10. Why i don't know. But i have tried it on Ubuntu 15.10 AND successfully installed the OPENCV.